# What is the font used in the logo of Stack exchange beta sites?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I am quite curious.. I already have seen it elsewere and I like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's called Sketch Rockwell. 
http://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Sketch_Rockwell.htm

There's also a face called ChunkFive that's similar: 
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/ChunkFive

Answer (score 2):

The font used is actually **Sketch Block**, which can be downloaded here:

http://www.dafont.com/sketch-block.font

[image]

Edit: Sketch Rockwell is the same font under a different name, apparently. Oops!

Comment: It's worth noting that Sketch Rockwell sometimes causes printing problems. I've not tried Sketch Block.